# Sign Addressing Elements on SOAP Message

Tags: java, soap, java-8, digital-signature

I need to sign a SOAPMessage signing the body and the header elements (BinarySecurityToken, Timestamp, To, Action, ReplyTo, FaultTo and MessageID). The header elements are created just before the sign. I'm using jdk8.

The problem I'm facing is that the Addressing elements are not working as I expected.
I create the SOAPElemnents this way

`SOAPElement to = securityElement.addChildElement("To", "wsa");
to.addAttribute(soapEnvelope.createName("Id", "wsa", "http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"), "To");
to.addTextNode("URL...");`

Next is creating the Reference

`Reference refTo = xmlSignatureFactory.newReference("#To", digestMethod, transformList, null, null);`

But when I try to make the DOMSignContext I can't set the IdAttributeNS
`signContext.setIdAttributeNS(addressingElements.get("To"), "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd", "Id");`

The error I'm getting is:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Id is not an attribute
at javax.xml.crypto.dom.DOMCryptoContext.setIdAttributeNS(DOMCryptoContext.java:204)`

Any help is welcome.
Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, just realized I got the NamespaceURI wrong, seems to be a bad copy-paste.

The correct Reference is:
`signContext.setIdAttributeNS(addressingElements.get("To"), "http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing", "Id");`

Comment: You can edit your question. Don't post question details as an answer to the question.